# d3.js t.map is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Hope somebody can help me out because I can't find any reference about this error.

I was working on this piece of code:

```
var xMin = d3.min(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
var xMax = d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.value; });

if (0 > xMin & 0 > xMax) {
  xMax = 0;
}

if (0 < xMin & 0 < xMax) { 
  xMin = 0;
}

x.domain(xMin, xMax).nice();
y.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.label; }));
```

but I must have made some mistake cause now the loading blocks with the error message below in the web console:

> "TypeError: t.map is not a function @ http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js:2

Comment: Should be `x.domain([xMin, xMax]).nice()`.

Comment: thank you! That was exactly the problem!

Comment: Added as answer for reference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`.domain()` takes an array as argument, i.e.

```
x.domain(xMin, xMax).nice();
```

should be

```
x.domain([xMin, xMax]).nice();
```

Comment: I got this same error with ChartistJS(with it's gem on chartist), this solved it -- input value was a string, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when I switched the mock data from an example.

```
   var dataset = d3.layout.stack()(["CountPending", "CountDenied"].map(function (type) {
            return data.map(function (d) {
                return { x: d.Name, y: +d[type] };
            });
        }));
```

In my dataset the example data was using `["pending","denied"]` while my real data used the following keys `["CountPending", "CountDenied"]`

Use the right keys!

While this might not help the OP, I hope it helps someone.