# d3.js error - not a function

Tags: javascript, html, json, d3.js

I'm trying to visualise data, which I imported with a MySQL query in a php file, using a d3.js pie chart I found online. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Status Codes</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h1>HTTP Status Codes</h1>

    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <script>

        function output(inp) {
            document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('pre')).innerHTML = inp;
        }

        d3.json("get_data.php", function(error, data) {

            var summarizedByKey = d3.nest()
                .key(function(d) { return d.statuscode; })
                .rollup(function(v) { return v.length; })
                .entries(data);

            var summarizedByStatuscode = JSON.stringify(summarizedByKey, undefined, 2);
            output(summarizedByStatuscode);

            var margin = {top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 20, left: 20};
                width = 350 - margin.left - margin.right;
                height = width - margin.top - margin.bottom;

            var chart = d3.select("body")
                .append('svg')
                .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + ((width/2)+margin.left) + "," + ((height/2)+margin.top) + ")");

            var radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .range(["#3399FF", "#5DAEF8", "#86C3FA", "#ADD6FB", "#D6EBFD"]);

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                .outerRadius(radius)
                .innerRadius(radius - 35);

            var pie = d3.layout.pie()
                .sort(null)
                .startAngle(1.1*Math.PI)
                .endAngle(3.1*Math.PI)
                .values(function(d) { return d.values; });

            var g = chart.selectAll(".arc")
                .summarizedByStatuscode(pie(summarizedByStatuscode))
                .enter().append("g")
                .attr("class", "arc");

            g.append("path")
                .attr("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })
                .transition()
                .ease("exp")
                .duration(2000)
                .attrTween("d", tweenPie);

            function tweenPie(b) {
                var i = d3.interpolate({startAngle: 1.1*Math.PI, endAngle: 1.1*Math.PI}, b);
                return function(t) { return arc(i(t)); };
            }

        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

When calling the function "output" with the argument summarizedByKey I get the following result:

```
[
  {
    "key": "200",
    "values": 227
  },
  {
    "key": "301",
    "values": 9
  }
]
```

When opening the html file in chrome I get the following error:

```
d3.layout.pie(...).sort(...).startAngle(...).endAngle(...).values is not a function

(anonymous function) @ statuscodes.html:53
(anonymous function) @ d3.v3.min.js:1
t @ d3.v3.min.js:1
u @ d3.v3.min.js:1)
```

Could someone help me fix this error?

Comment: Do you have the code for the original chart that you found online? It's a bit hard to tell what's going on without seeing what its author had initially done.

Comment: @scrollex Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/Nw62g/3/

Comment: @scrollex I think I found the error! " .values" in "var pie" shoould probably be "value". Though I messed around with the code for a long time now I didn't see that!

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: a.map is not a function

Comment: Nice work! Yeah, was going to say, usually that sort of thing results from typos rather than some sort of deeper technical snafu.

Comment: Initial hunch is that you need to be using an array somewhere that you're not: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17088916/d3-js-t-map-is-not-a-function

Comment: @scrollex Ah yes the problem is that the array gets stored as string. Thanks for your advice! Is there any way to import the data correctly?

Comment: It's working now! I generated the array of objects myself and passed it to the d3.js code: 

   (`var dataByKey = [];

     for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
      var key = {};
      key["statuscode"] = summarizedByKey[i].key;
      key["values"] = summarizedByKey[i].values;
      dataByKey.push(key);
     };`)